# Does the Javascript Firestore client cache document references?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Just in case I'm trying to solve the XY problem here, here's some context (domain is a role-playing game companion app). I have a document (campaign), which has a collection (characters), and I'm working with angular.io / angularfire.

The core problem here is that if I query the collection of characters on a campaign, I get back `Observable<Character[]>`. I can use that in an `*ngFor let character of characters | async` just fine, but this ends up being a little messy downstream - I really want to do something like have the attributes block as a standalone component (`<character-attributes [character]="character">`) and so on.

This ends up meaning down in the actual display components, I have a mixture of items that change via ngOnChanges (stuff that comes from the character) and items that are observable (things injected by global services like the User playing a particular Character).

I have a couple options for making this cleaner (the zeroth being: just ignore it).

*One*: I could flatten all the possible dependencies into scalars instead of observables (probably by treating things like the attributes as a real only-view component and injecting more data as a direct input - `<character-attributes [character]="" [player]="" [gm]="">` etc. Displayable changes kind of take care of themselves.

*Two*: I could find some magical way to convert an `Observable<Character[]>` into an `Observable<Observable<Character>[]>` which is kind of what I want, and then pass the Character observable down into the various character display blocks (there's a few different display options, depending on whether you're a player (so you want much more details of your character, and small info on everything else) or a GM (so you want intermediate details on everything that can expand into details anywhere).

*Three*: Instead of passing a whole `Character` into my component, I could pass `character.id` and have child components construct an observable for it in `ngOnInit`. (or maybe `switchMap` in ngOnChanges, it's unclear if the angular runtime will reuse actual components for different items by changing out the arguments, but that's a different stack overflow question). In this case, I'd be doing multiple reads of the same document - once in a query to get all characters, and once in each view component that is given the characterId and needs to fetch an observable of the character in question.

**So the question is**: if I do `firestore.collection('/foo/1/bars').valueChanges()` and later do `firestore.doc('/foo/1/bars/1').valueChanges()` in three different locations in the code, does that call four firestore reads (for billing purposes), one read, or two (one for the query and one for the doc)?

I dug into the firebase javascript sdk, and it [looks like](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/b07f822bdb4cf628d53d337dc0df3db7f865a5aa/packages/firestore/src/core/event_manager.ts#L87) it's possible that the eventmanager handles multiple queries for the same item by just maintaining an array of listeners, but I quite frankly am not confident in my code archaeology here yet.

There's probably an option four here somewhere too. I might be over-engineering this, but this particular toy project is primarily so I can wrestle with best-practices in firestore, so I want to figure out what the right approach is.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about how you are querying these documents.  Simply calling `firestore.collection('/foo/1/bars')` doesn't cost anything at all, since it just creates a local reference to a collection and doesn't actually read anything.  It's not until you attach a listener or call get() that anything is read or billed.

Comment: sure - I'm calling `.valueChanges()` on both.  [doc ref](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges) [collection ref](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#streaming-collection-data)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code linked from the SDK and it **might be** the library is smart enough to optimize multiple observers of the same document to just read the document once. However this is an implementation detail that is dangerous to rely on, as it could change without notice because it's not part of the public API.

On one hand, if you have the danger above in mind and are still willing to investigate, then you may create some test program to discover how things work as of today, either by checking the reads usage from the Console UI or by temporarily modifying the SDK source adding some logging to help you understand what's happening under the hood.

On the other hand, I believe part of the question arises from a application state management perspective. In fact, both listening to the collection or listening to each individual document will notify the same changes to the app, IMO what differs here is how data will flow across the components and how these changes will be managed. In that aspect I would chose whatever approach feels better codewise.

Hope this helps somewhat.